# Scala: break outer function from inner function

Tags: scala

***What I have***

I have a function below (I can't change *outer* function)

```
def outer(x: Int, inner: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    inner(x)
    false
}
```

***What I want***

Define *inner* function in such way that: if (x == 10) *outer* function return **true**

```
def inner(x: Int): Boolean = {
  if (x == 10) OUTER_FUNCTION_SHOULD_RETURN_TRUE!!!
  else false
}

outer(10, inner) // TRUE!!
```

***Question***

*How can I do it?*

***Edit:***

I use the next trick:

```
// If inner return true at least once, then outerWraper return true
def outerWrapper(x: Int, inner: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
  var flag = false

  def inner2(e: Int): Boolean = {     
    if (!flag) flag = inner(e)
    inner(e)
  }

  outer(x, p2)  
  flag
}
```

*Can I avoid using var flag, but use val insted? As I understand var is a bad style in Scala*

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that without changing the `outer` function!

Comment: Also, should it not be `outer(10,inner) // TRUE!!` ?

Comment: thnks, already correct

Comment: First, this looks like homework from the Coursera course, so giving you a full solution would not be appropriate. That said, as a hint on writing `exists` (which if I understand the question correctly is ultimately what you are stuck on): don't reuse `forall` - you only need to check entries in the set until you find a match, so write a tail-recursive inner method that will work that way.

Comment: From Coursera: Using forall, implement a function exists which tests whether a set contains at least one element for which the given predicate is true. Note that the functions forall and exists behave like the universal and existential quantifiers of first-order logic.

Comment: If its a Coursera assignment, you'll be really learn a lot if try to solve it yourself. I have learnt Scala from Coursera itself !

Comment: I've already done the task by myself. As you can see, exists method is implemented and it works well. But I search for way to solve this task better

Comment: Be careful @NickoleAbs, others might copy your implementation!

Comment: I'll remove it soon )

Comment: @NickoleAbs I had forgotten it defined the exercise that way. In that case, yes, it can be simpler (and pure functional - no vars) - think in terms of !p

Comment: Further hint: say you are looking for even numbers - if there are none in the set, then what must be true for all elements of the set? You should find that the simplest solution for `exists` is actually a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks!!! I grasp the solution

Comment: Also, it's ok to use vars inside of functions. You just don't want to leak them to the outside, of the function or class. You just need to make sure you understand if there are leakages to the rest of your app. Use mutable only locally and if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, the last expression is returned unless you use the `return` keyword. In your case, the function `outer` always returns `false`.

Since you just wrap the inner function you could remove the `false`:

```
def outer(x: Int, inner: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
  inner(x)
}

def inner(x: Int): Boolean = {
  if (x == 10) true else false
}
```

Or, even shorter:

```
def inner(x: Int): Boolean = {
  x == 10
}
```

This would return the returned expression of the inner function, namely `true` if `x == 10`, otherwise `false`.

Comment: I know, but I can't chanhe the outer function

Comment: If the other function really looks like the one you posted, then it will always return false because the last expression (`false`) is returned. There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: can I avoid using var, but use val instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you can define your wrapper, you probably can avoid using `var`

```
def outerWrapper(x: Int, f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    if (f(x)) true
    else outer(x, f)
}
```

Then you can pass `inner` method to `outerWrapper` method

```
outerWrapper(10,inner)
```

Answer (score 0):

My method is here:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks
def outer(x: Int, inner: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
  Breaks.breakable {
    inner(x)
    return false
  }
  true
}

def inner(x: Int): Boolean = {
  if (x == 10) Breaks.break()
  else false
}

println(outer(10, inner)) // TRUE!!
```